# C++ libcurl set proxy from a configuration file

Tags: c++, linux, libcurl

I use libcurl to make some http tests and managed to configure the proxy settings from code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, _PROXY);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, USERPASS);
```

I am testing on linux and I want to know if I can use some configuration file to configure the proxy settings.

Comment: Do you mean curl library uses some configuration file to read these (such as proxy etc.) details?

Comment: Yes. Curl command reads ~/.curlrc. I wanted to know in libcurl reads such file?